# Showing only Last Selected Item from CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, checkboxlist

I'm attempting to databind a CheckBoxList but only the last item is being selected.

ASPX:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CityCheckBoxList" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="SqlDS1" DataTextField="City" 
    DataValueField="CityID" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDS1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code Behind:

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        EmployeeIdTextBox.Text = sdr["EmployeeID"].ToString();
        EmployeeNameTextBox.Text = sdr["EmployeeName"].ToString();

        CityCheckBoxList.DataBind();
        ListItem currentCheckBox = CityCheckBoxList.Items.FindByValue(sdr["CityID"].ToString());
        if (currentCheckBox != null)
        {
            currentCheckBox.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If the employee belongs to more than one city, only the last one is showing checked in the CityCheckBoxList. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If employee has multiple cities, how this is stored in DB? In other words, what is the output of the `sdr["CityID"].ToString()` when employee has more than one city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because you are binding `CityCheckBoxList` on every employee from the database. Data binding for checkboxes should be moved outside the loop. Try this:

```
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    CityCheckBoxList.DataBind();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        EmployeeIdTextBox.Text = sdr["EmployeeID"].ToString();
        EmployeeNameTextBox.Text = sdr["EmployeeName"].ToString();    

        ListItem currentCheckBox = CityCheckBoxList.Items.FindByValue(sdr["CityID"].ToString());
        if (currentCheckBox != null)
        {
            currentCheckBox.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```